# Link not updated in preview of suggested edit

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, hyperlinks

I was reviewing a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2238201) that only fixed a broken link.  Before approving the new link I wanted to test it, so I clicked on the new link in the preview, but found it was broken.  On further inspection I found that although the visible text of the new link had changed, the actual HTML link had not.  Here's an excerpt from the HTML, with a bit of whitespace added for readability:

```
<p> Now I am using fabric js library. 
  <a href="http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/" rel="nofollow">
  <span class="diff-add">https</span>://github.com<span class="diff-add">/kangax</span>/fabric.js/
  </a>
</p>
```

Although the edit was accepted and the suggested edit page now had the correct link linked, you can see that the first reviewer saw the same problem I did, as he rejected the edit with the comment "new address does not work either".

I hope it is obvious that this is a bug.

Comment: The link had changed from http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/ to https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/. I don't see how this is a bug... just bad reviewers.

Comment: @Ben, please read the question carefully.  The viewable text in the preview had changed, but the `href` in the `a` tag had not changed.  That's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be something of a caching issue?

```
<p>Now I am using fabric js library. <a href="https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/" rel="nofollow">https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/</a></p>
```

That's how it appears for me.

Have a pat on the back for helping keep the site clean and not robo-reviewing!

Comment: Why is it not a bug that the text `https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/` was hyperlinked to `http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/` in the preview?

Comment: @OldPro I just checked the HTML rendering. For me, it appears exactly as above: the new link is as it should be.

Comment: Yes, I said in the question that the link is correctly rendered _now_, but it was not correctly rendered when I or at least one other viewer reviewed it.

Comment: @Old I don't think that was in your question - beside the point, I'm not sure there's any way to confirm or even [meta-tag:status-review] this without another instance of this happening. Additionally, you might have unintentionally copied the HTML out of the original answer, if you did so from within the review window. Did you check both HTML excerpts?

Comment: _Although the edit was accepted and the suggested edit page now ha[s] the correct link linked..._  The HTML in the original answer had both text and hyperlink of `http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/`.  Besides, the genesis of this question was that I clicked on `https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/` but was taken to `http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/`

Comment: @OldPro That's _really_ strange. All I (and I think anyone) can say is, let us know if it happens again? Beyond that, I'm not sure...